# execute linux command background in php

Tags: php, shell-exec

I need to execute a command in linux by using php and it should meet following requirement.

- should create log file
- should run as background

I know how to do it separately,

with log file :

```
shell_exec("command 1>log 2>&1");
```

as background:

```
shell_exec("command /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

My question is how to do it together ?

Comment: Actually your second example does _not_ run the command "in background" by which people typically mean "without the calling process to wait for it to finish". You need to detach the controlling console for that: `shell_exec("nohup command /dev/null 2>&1 &");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shell_exec("command 1>log 2>&1 &");
```